# WebView getVideo/Audio tracks or MediaStream and send it to the server via WebRTC

Tags: android, video, webview, webrtc, mediastream

I have to get video/audio tracks or if it's possible MediaStream object from the Android WebView which plays HLS stream ("m3m8").

I load HLS stream in the WebView using method loadUrl("...m3m8"). It's running without issues, but i can't figure out how to get live video and audio tracks from the HLS stream. I read a lot of articles and I was not able to find any solution. So my question is - Is it possible to get audio and video tracks from the running HLS stream on the WebView? I need to get the audio and video tracks because I should send them via PeerConnection(WebRTC) which accepts MediaStream or audio tracks and video tracks. Any ideas and examples will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For example in the JS language the video element has options like "captureStream", "mozCaptureStream". Are there any functions in Android like these in JS?

Comment: Did you mean **M3U8** for HLS? Or does the file link really end with `.m3m8`?

Comment: The file link end with m3m8 but for security reasons I am not able to share it @VC.One

Comment: What you can do, though, is check how an HLS playlist file looks like, and tell us if your confidential file looks like that or not :-).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to check it how it's look like.

Comment: Well your Android app must have access to it if you call `loadUrl("*.m3m8")`...

Comment: I can share our public for testing purposes .m3m8 file - https://as2.12all.tv/play/bnt1/index.m3u8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLS works by defining a playlist (your `.m3u8` file) which points to chunks of the video (say `segment00000.ts`, `segment00001.ts`, ...). It can contain different streams for different resolutions, but the idea (very simplified) is that your player can download a chunk, play it right away, and download the next one in the meantime.

A WebRTC video track takes RTP packets. I don't know exactly what the Android API exposes, but it feels like either you can pass it an `m3u8` as a source (though that may be a bit weird for a generic API), or you can't, and you have to read the HLS stream yourself, extract RTP frames, and pass them to WebRTC.

For instance, [gstreamer's hlsdemux](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/hls/hlsdemux.html?gi-language=c#hlsdemux) seems to be able to read from an HLS source. From there you could extract RTP frames and feed them to your WebRTC track.

Probably that's a bit lower-level than you hoped, but if the Android API doesn't do it for you, you have to do it yourself (or find a library that does it).

Comment: Thank you for the information, but the issue starts with that our backend returns live stream (.m3m8) in video.js. So for the playing the stream I tried ExoPlayer,  Android MediaPlayer without success. Only on the WebView component I am able to play that stream. So for that I am looking for examples or for an answer how to get the stream audio tracks/video tracks or MediaStream from the WebView component. Is this possible at all?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a video player to proxy the video stream (e.g. convert from HLS to WebRTC or RTP). Do ExoPlayer and Android MediaPlayer do that?

Comment: Yes, you are right, they don't do that.

Comment: Hence my answer above: if you need to translate HLS to WebRTC, you probably need to do it yourself or find a library that does it for you. In parallel, you can feed the HLS stream to a viewer to show it in your app